# Firefox addon development, how to change about:config setting

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Hi I'm trying to develop a simple addon which opens a web page different from firefox default page in new tab. I want to change two of the default settings values in about:config, but it seems I cannot achieve this through my current configuration.

I'm using the Add-On SDK recommended by firefox to develop the add-on.([creating a simple add-on using the SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started)

By looking into the about:config setting, I found that if I set "browser.newtab.url" to the web page url, and "moa.ntab.openInNewTab" from true to false, I can realize such function. So I followed the tutorial above and added ./defaults/preferences/pref.js for changing the config.

My current directory looks like this:

```
ff-addon
  └─ data
  └─ defaults
     └─ preferences
        └─pref.js
  └─ lib
     └─ main.js
  └─ package.json
  └─ test
     └─ test-main.js
```

the pref.js code in the /defaults/preferences directory is as follows:

```
pref("browser.newtab.url", "http://www.baidu.com");
pref("moa.ntab.openInNewTab", false);
```

I did not change the code in main.js. Code of it is shown below:

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Visit Mozilla",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  tabs.open("http://www.mozilla.org/");
}
```

I did not change the code in package.json either:

```
{
  "name": "ff-addon",
  "title": "ff-addon",
  "id": "jid1-mPDAO4AqY5w17w",
  "description": "a basic add-on",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MPL 2.0",
  "version": "0.1"
}
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong or maybe what I can follow in finishing such simple functions... Thank you so much!

Comment: I am browsing the official tutorial, and I find something. [preferences/service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/preferences_service)

Answer (score 1):

As the first comment says, see the documentation for [sdk/preferences/service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/preferences_service).

Here's a quick example:

```
var name = "extensions.checkCompatibility.nightly";
require("sdk/preferences/service").set(name, false)
```